# use MinGW to create exe file in windows from GNU source package

Tags: windows, compilation, mingw, gnu, cflow

the basic idea was, I wanted to generate the call graph in text format for several c files. After googling around for long time, i found cflow, which can deliver everything I want, but it is only runable in Linux or else. Then I began to search how to compile the cflow source files on the web to a exe file. I found MinGW which should be able to do the cross-platform compilation.

After installing the MinGW and the MSYS and running the usual commands "./configure; make; make install", I simply got an error that "mkdir" was not found. Actually. Actually I was wondering whether this is the correct way to compile the whole package.

Does anyone has an idea how I can build the cflow.exe correctly in Windows? If there is a tutorial or something like this, I will be very thankful.

Song

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Please try this Github repository "MinGW + MSYS build of GNU cflow 1.4" (For Windows).
https://github.com/noahp/cflow-mingw

It contains already compiled "cflow.exe",and an instruction about how to build cflow using mingw and msys.

## Test

System Environment:Win 8.1 (x64)

1.I tested the "cflow.exe" downloaded from the github repository , and amazingly it worked!

2.I followed the mingw compiling instruction,and it successfully compiled "cflow 1.5".

Command:

```
bash configure  
make
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do that today. I'm using cygwin, after installing gcc, binutils, make and after downloading the gnu cflow.tar.gz, it was as easy as `./configure ; make ; make install`.

Comment: and what about cygwin?